# jQuery trigger click in loop stops after the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do this, but the loop ends after the first trigger. Any ideas to help me out?

```
$(document).on('click', '#configurator .myalbumimgs .autofill', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var nb_of_images = $('#grid div.configimg').length;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_of_images; i++) {

        alert(i);

        $('.imgpicker .photo .add').eq(i).trigger('click');
    }

});
```

Edit 1: Everything works fine if I remove $('.imgpicker .photo .add').eq(i).trigger('click'); and just let the loop run.

If I put a number in, like eq(3) selects the right one, but only that one. Then it stops as before.

No errors in console :S

Edit 2: Found out the correct solution, my mistake with .eq on the wrong element. Thanks for all suggestions! Correct code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#configurator .myalbumimgs .autofill', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).not('.done')) {

        var multiselector_nbimages = $('#grid').attr('data-nbimages');

        var nb_images_selected = parseInt($('#grid div.configimg').not('.temp').length);
        var max_nb_images = parseInt(multiselector_nbimages);

        if (nb_images_selected < max_nb_images) {

            var album_images = $(this).parent().parent().children('.imgpicker').children('.photo');
            var nb_of_grid_images = $('#grid div.configimg.temp').length;

            for (i = 0; i < nb_of_grid_images; i++) {

                album_images.eq(i).children('.add').not('.selected').trigger('click');;
            }

            $(this).addClass('done');

        } else {

            alert(lang_valid_max_nb_of_photos);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: @Alexander length is a protperty...

Comment: check the console for errors. It probably breaks because of error

Comment: Any console errors, and you should do .length -1, since you are starting from 0 in loop , and length counts from 1

Comment: @noitse he has "<", not "<=", no need to minus one the length. It will stop when needed.

Comment: @noitse that is false. He won't get the last element in loop since he uses <, not <=

Comment: One hint I have: make `i` a local variable (right now its a global).

Comment: Please, show the handler code of the click event that you fire.

Comment: @noitse Everything works fine if I remove $('.imgpicker .photo .add').eq(i).trigger('click'); and just let the loop run. No errors in console :S

Comment: Could you please provide jsfiddle, that would represent this part of code

Comment: Here is an jsfiddle example i have made (ofc it is not same as yours since i dont know the structure https://jsfiddle.net/a0ubLkva/), there must be one problem with your loop, and i think the problem is that your selector '$('.imgpicker .photo .add').eq(i)' does not exist , try putting console .log for your selector and you will see that it will probably return undefined.

Answer (score -2):

jquery has built in each method .

```
$('#configurator .albumbtn.autofill').on('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

//Iterate through every configimg
$('#grid div.configimg').each(function(el) {
// $(this) is current element in the list
   if($(this).hasClass('someclass')) { $(this).trigger('click') }
})
```

});